# Speed the response time of the Query

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, execution-plan, sql-server-2017

So I have this query that I am using on an API endpoint, the query takes between 3-4 seconds to run, returning a small OFFSET of 10 rows. Is there a way I can put indexes somewhere or improve on string_agg to load this query under 1 second?

```
SELECT DISTINCT SC.Id,
                SC.Name                                                   AS InsuredName,
                SC.CFLegalName                                            AS LegalName,
                SC.TaxID,
                SC.Address,
                SC.CFAddress2                                             AS Address2,
                SC.City,
                SC.State,
                SC.ZipCode                                                AS PostalCode,
                SC.CountryID,
                SC.ContactFullName                                        AS ContactName,
                SC.ContactPhone,
                SC.CFContactFax                                           AS ContactFax,
                SC.MainEmail                                              AS ContactEmail,
                SC.CFInsuredDescription                                   AS InsuredDescription,
                SC.CFVendor                                               AS Vendor,
                SC.CFNote                                                 AS Note,
                (case when SC.Archive is null then 0 else SC.Archive end) as archive,
                (
                    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(SCS.Status AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '|') 
                    FROM dbo.SubcontractorsStatus SCS
                             INNER JOIN dbo.Hiringclients_Subcontractors HCS
                                        ON HCS.SubContractorId = SC.Id
                    WHERE SCS.Id = HCS.SubcontractorStatusID
                )                                                         AS Status
        ,
                (
                    SELECT STRING_AGG(
                                   CAST(CONCAT_WS('|', PR.Id, PR.Name)
                                       AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ','
                               )
                    FROM dbo.Projects PR
                             INNER JOIN dbo.ProjectsInsureds PRI ON PRI.InsuredID = SC.Id
                    WHERE PR.Id = PRI.ProjectID
                      AND (PR.Archived IS NULL OR PR.Archived = 0)
                )                                                         AS ProjectName
        ,
                (
                    SELECT STRING_AGG(
                                   CAST(CONCAT_WS('|', HC.Name, Hc.Id)
                                       AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ','
                               ) 
                    FROM dbo.Hiringclients HC
                             INNER JOIN dbo.Hiringclients_Subcontractors HCS ON 
                              HCS.HiringClientId = HC.Id
                              AND HCS.SubContractorId = SC.Id
                        
                        AND (HC.Archive IS NULL OR HC.Archive = 0)
                )                                                         AS HolderName  
FROM dbo.SubContractors SC
         INNER JOIN dbo.Hiringclients_Subcontractors HCS ON HCS.SubContractorId = SC.Id
         INNER JOIN dbo.HiringClient_EnabledSystems ES ON ES.HiringClientID = HCS.HiringClientId
         INNER JOIN dbo.Hiringclients HC ON HC.Id = HCS.HiringClientId
WHERE ES.cfEnabled = 1
  AND (SC.Archive IS NULL OR SC.Archive = 0)
GROUP BY SC.Id
       , SC.Name
       , SC.CFLegalName
       , SC.TaxID
       , SC.Address
       , SC.CFAddress2
       , SC.City
       , SC.State
       , SC.ZipCode
       , SC.CountryID
       , SC.ContactFullName
       , SC.ContactPhone
       , SC.CFContactFax
       , SC.MainEmail
       , SC.CFInsuredDescription
       , SC.CFVendor
       , SC.CFNote
       , SC.Archive
ORDER BY insuredName ASC
OFFSET 10 * (100 - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

I have following indexes:   ​

- HiringClients: Clustered(id), NonClustered(Name)
- Subcontractors: Clustered(id), NonClustered(Name)
- Hiringclients_Subcontractors: Clustered(HiringClientID, SubContractorId), NonClustered(SubcontractorStatusID)
- Projects: NonClustered(ProjectId, InsuredID)

Also find below the attached execution plan (cannot post a picture as it's pretty big):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gecwimqfy0meu54/executionPlan.sqlplan?dl=0

SQL Server Version: 2017

Comment: Pick one:  `NULL` or `0`.  That will simplify some expressions, such as `Archive`.

Comment: Could you include the SQL Server version and use Paste the Plan (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for those of us who don't have drop box.

Comment: @armitage paste the plan is failing as I think the execution plan is too large for it to process... added sql server version

Comment: Consider using [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) instead: this has the downside of not being able to jump to a specific page number, only a specific key, but is much, much faster. And why do you have those three `INNER JOIN`'s they don't seem to be serving any purpose (or at least they are repeated in the subqueries), so it looks like the whole thing could do with some significant simplification. Furthermore `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` together is usually a bad sign

Answer (score 2):

There are two [Eager Index Spool](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/starting-sql/starting-sql-eager-index-spools/) operators consuming a significant amount of time (1.538 + 1.828 seconds) in the plan.

[image]

and

[image]

You might consider creating a new index for that, or perhaps modifying an existing index.  The spool is reading from the non-clustered index `HiringClients_SubContractors.ix_hc_sc_status` and essentially rewriting it as if the definition was:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_hc_sc_status_rewrite
ON dbo.Hiringclients_SubContractors (SubContractorId, HiringClientId);
```

I would create the index above, and test the outcome to see what difference it might make.  Obviously, you might want to evaluate replacing the existing `ix_hc_sc_status` index with this one.

I would also consider splitting the `Status`, `ProjectName`, and `HolderName` subqueries out of the main query, and insert the results of each into a temporary table.  Then join the main query to each of those temporary tables.

Doing so will allow the SQL Server optimizer to better understand the cardinality of each of the tables involved, and thereby provide a better, more efficient plan.  Something like this should work:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Status, #ProjectName, #HolderName;

SELECT sa = STRING_AGG(CAST(SCS.Status AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '|') 
    , HCS.SubContractorId
INTO #Status
FROM dbo.SubcontractorsStatus SCS
    INNER JOIN dbo.Hiringclients_Subcontractors HCS
        ON SCS.Id = HCS.SubcontractorStatusID;


SELECT sa = STRING_AGG(
                CAST(CONCAT_WS('|', PR.Id, PR.Name)
                    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ','
            )
    , PRI.InsuredID
INTO #ProjectName
FROM dbo.Projects PR
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProjectsInsureds PRI 
        ON PR.Id = PRI.ProjectID
            AND (PR.Archived IS NULL OR PR.Archived = 0)

SELECT sa = STRING_AGG(
                CAST(CONCAT_WS('|', HC.Name, Hc.Id)
                    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ','
            )
    , HCS.SubContractorId
INTO #HolderName
FROM dbo.Hiringclients HC
    INNER JOIN dbo.Hiringclients_Subcontractors HCS 
        ON HCS.HiringClientId = HC.Id
            AND (HC.Archive IS NULL OR HC.Archive = 0)


SELECT DISTINCT SC.Id,
                SC.Name                                                   AS InsuredName,
                SC.CFLegalName                                            AS LegalName,
                SC.TaxID,
                SC.Address,
                SC.CFAddress2                                             AS Address2,
                SC.City,
                SC.State,
                SC.ZipCode                                                AS PostalCode,
                SC.CountryID,
                SC.ContactFullName                                        AS ContactName,
                SC.ContactPhone,
                SC.CFContactFax                                           AS ContactFax,
                SC.MainEmail                                              AS ContactEmail,
                SC.CFInsuredDescription                                   AS InsuredDescription,
                SC.CFVendor                                               AS Vendor,
                SC.CFNote                                                 AS Note,
                (case when SC.Archive is null then 0 else SC.Archive end) as archive,
                s.sa                                                      AS Status,
                p.sa                                                      AS ProjectName,
                h.sa                                                      AS HolderName  
FROM dbo.SubContractors SC
         INNER JOIN dbo.Hiringclients_Subcontractors HCS ON HCS.SubContractorId = SC.Id
         INNER JOIN dbo.HiringClient_EnabledSystems ES ON ES.HiringClientID = HCS.HiringClientId
         INNER JOIN dbo.Hiringclients HC ON HC.Id = HCS.HiringClientId
         LEFT JOIN #Status s ON s.SubContractorID  = SC.ID
         LEFT JOIN #ProjectName p ON p.InsuredID = SC.ID
         LEFT JOIN #HolderName h ON h.SubContractorId = SC.Id
WHERE ES.cfEnabled = 1
  AND (SC.Archive IS NULL OR SC.Archive = 0)
GROUP BY SC.Id
       , SC.Name
       , SC.CFLegalName
       , SC.TaxID
       , SC.Address
       , SC.CFAddress2
       , SC.City
       , SC.State
       , SC.ZipCode
       , SC.CountryID
       , SC.ContactFullName
       , SC.ContactPhone
       , SC.CFContactFax
       , SC.MainEmail
       , SC.CFInsuredDescription
       , SC.CFVendor
       , SC.CFNote
       , SC.Archive
ORDER BY insuredName ASC
OFFSET 10 * (100 - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Also:

1. I noticed the `OFFSET` clause seems wrong since it is hard-coded to start at 990, and fetch the next 10 rows - each time you run this it will return the same rows defeating the purpose of the `OFFSET` clause.
2. You have a `DISTINCT` at the start of the query, but then you use a `GROUP BY` clause *as well*.  That's a bit of a code-smell to me.
3. Converting to an `nvarchar(max)` data type can also cause an excessively large memory grant - make sure you really need to have room for more than 4000 characters in those spots, and if you don't then specify a realistic value for the `nvarchar()` columns.
4. It's awesome that you included a link to the entire query plan.  It shows that some of the statistics objects involved haven't been updated in a while.  I would make sure you have a scheduled job to update stats as frequently as makes sense.  I wrote a blog post showing how to [automate statistics updates](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/maintenance/statistics-update-job/) via SQL Server Agent.

Comment: thanks so much for the breakdown. I am using a parameter on main application to pass to offset, and thank you for pointing out distinct :)